# Definition of addition/multiplication in $\mathbb{F}$

Tags: field-theory

I have a question that says (in order): 
Describe the smallest field $\mathbb{F}$ in which the equation $x^2 - 5 = 0$ has a solution. (I think it is $\mathbb{R}$).
Then it asks: Carefully explain why every nonzero element of $\mathbb{F}$ has a multiplicative inverse.
Isn't this the axiom of a field, that each non-zero element of a field has a multiplicative inverse or am i missing something?

Comment: Just to correct the terminology, it is the _definition_ of a field, not axiom of a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question i would argue that $\mathbb F_2$ is the answer, because there $5=1+1+1+1+1=1$ and $x^2-1=0$ has the solution $x=1$.

The second question: in my opinion your answer is right. Maybe they wanted that you show that more explicitly for the field $\mathbb F$ as an answer to the first question. In that case: $1\in \mathbb F_2$ has multiplicative inverse $1$.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to group theory, what does $\mathbb{F}_2$ denote? Also, why does $1+1+1+1+1$ equal to $1$? I actually left out the middle part which was "describe multiplication and addition in $\mathbb{F}$" because I also thought it was an axiom as well... (that they're closed under addition, under multiplication, associative and commutative).

Comment: here is some information about the field: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2). It is as simple as a field can be, because it has only two elements

Answer (score 2):

The smallest infinite field in which the equation $x^2-5=0$ has a solution is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. But remark, that $\mathbb{F}_2$ isn't contained in $\mathbb{Q}$ or some field extension.